# Hide front-end from every logged out user and redirect them to the default login page

Tags: user-roles, user-access, wp-login-form, content-restriction

I want to hide the front-end from every visitor/logged out user. To see the front-end, every user must have been registered and logged in.

Any visitor that's logged out should be redirected to the default WordPress login page.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this would be to add the code below to the top of your template file(s):

```
<?php // redirect to login page if user is not logged in 
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) :
    header('Location: /wp-login.php');
    exit();
endif;
?>
```

There are some subtleties around [redirecting in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-do-i-make-a-redirect-in-php) that you may want to consider, but for me the above code works.

Comment: Also, you may find the [New User Approve plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/new-user-approve/) useful.

Comment: Thankyou for the help but can you please give more detail about where exactly i have to put this code?

Comment: It would be best if you have a child-theme and put this code at the top of the [template files](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#adding-template-files) you're using.

Comment: Here is a different approach of doing what you have in mind: [https://wordpress.org/support/topic/possible-to-make-entire-site-private-without-plugin/#post-12116149](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/possible-to-make-entire-site-private-without-plugin/#post-12116149). It's best to still use a child-theme if you aren't already yet. That makes your edits update-proof.